# KLC Trackpad driver on kernel 5.3?

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad

I had installed Pop_OS onto my MSI GS63 Stealth 8RE laptop, and so far everything has been working alright except for my trackpad. The one included is a SteelSeries KLC trackpad, and according to a hardware probe, it should work natively with built-in kernel drivers that have been in since 2.6. I'm fairly new to Linux, so I'm not entirely sure where to go at this point. I've tried searching for drivers, but the only things found are keyboard lighting controllers and Synaptic touchpad drivers, neither helping the situation. I've tried other distros such as Mint, and Fedora. It's worked on those, so I'm not sure why it isn't working on Pop_OS/Ubuntu. Any help would be appreciated.

[Here's my hardware probe](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=0f93c2d8d2)

[Here's my touchpad info](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:1038-1122)